# Highlight or underline the current selection in the wildmode list

Tags: wildmenu

I use the following wildmenu settings:

```
set wildmenu
set wildmode=list:full
```

Which results in this after typing `:find *foo<tab>`:

[image]

Is there a way to highlight the options in the wildmode list as opposed to (or in addition to) the highlighted options in the wildmenu?

Answer (score 2):

This would indeed be rather useful, but unfortunately this isn't possible.

The `showmatches()` function in `ex_getln.c` shows the list of completions:

```
/*
 * Show all matches for completion on the command line.
 * Returns EXPAND_NOTHING when the character that triggered expansion should
 * be inserted like a normal character.
 */
    static int
showmatches(xp, wildmenu)
```

I see no code for highlighting anything, except directory entries...

Answer (score 1):

The `WildMenu` highlight group is the highlighting for the current wildmenu match.
This would put an underline under your current match:

```
highlight WildMenu cterm=underline
```

A screenshot of it in action:
[image: wildmenu underline]

Comment: I may not have been clear enough - I'm fine with how the status line looks with regard to current match highlighting. What I want is for the items in the list appearing above the status line (when `set wildmode=list` is set) to be highlighted as well.

Comment: @broma0 I edited your answer to make it a bit clearer what you're asking for. (The "status line" you're referring to *is* the wildmenu.)

Comment: @broma0 I don't think the highlighting for that can be changed without affecting other colors.